# Google Maps - 75 Markers - DialogFragments

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin

I have 75 markers on the map and each of them, when clicked, brings up my subclass of DialogFragment. Fragment uses 3 strings stored in Strings.xml (3x75).

Is there a better way of recognizing the clicked marker and bringing up the DialogFragment with the corresponding info than writing 75 `if` statements like this (comparing its location to my `List<LatLng>` of all locations)

```
        var pos = e.Marker.Position;
        FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

        if (pos.Equals(mLokacije[0]))
        {
            dialog_Informacije informacijeDialog = new dialog_Informacije(GetString(Resource.String.lok1_naslov),
                GetString(Resource.String.lok1_sitno),
                GetString(Resource.String.lok1_opis),
                GetString(Resource.String.dialog_green));
            informacijeDialog.Show(transaction, "dialog fragment");
        }
        else if (pos.Equals(mLokacije[1]))
        {
            dialog_Informacije informacijeDialog = new dialog_Informacije(GetString(Resource.String.lok2_naslov),
                GetString(Resource.String.lok2_sitno),
                GetString(Resource.String.lok2_opis),
                GetString(Resource.String.dialog_red));
            informacijeDialog.Show(transaction, "dialog fragment");
        } 
       else if
       { ...
```

EDIT:

Locations are added like this

```
private void AddLocations()
    {
        mLokacije = new List<LatLng>();

        mLokacije.Add(new LatLng(43.511095, 16.436985)); //1
        mLokacije.Add(new LatLng(43.5095654, 16.4392571)); //2
        mLokacije.Add(new LatLng(43.5095598, 16.4393218)); //3
        mLokacije.Add(new LatLng(43.509010, 16.440499)); //4
        mLokacije.Add(new LatLng(43.509029, 16.440431)); //5
        mLokacije.Add(new LatLng(43.508883, 16.440532)); //6
        mLokacije.Add(new LatLng(43.508732, 16.440807)); //7
        mLokacije.Add(new LatLng(43.508815, 16.440154)); //8 ... }
```

-->this method is called in OnCreate

Markers are drawn like this:

```
 private void DrawMarkersAndFillColors()
    {
        mColors = new List<string>(new string[mLokacije.Count]);
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        for (int i = 0; i < mLokacije.Count; i++)
        {
            options.SetPosition(mLokacije[i]);
            switch (i)
            {
                case 55:
                case 57:
                case 60:
                    options.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueGreen));
                    mColors[i] = GetString(Resource.String.dialog_green);
                    break;
                case 43:
                case 46:
                case 52:
                    options.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueRed));
                    mColors[i] = GetString(Resource.String.dialog_red);
                    break; 
           .....}
       mMap.AddMarker(options);
       }
```

--> this is called in OnMapReady

FINAL EDIT:

Your solution works:

```
var indexPlus = mLokacije.FindIndex(position => position.Latitude == pos.Latitude && position.Longitude == pos.Longitude) + 1;
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Well, you can make a big hash_map for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the strings part, it´s easy. Make a method to get resource strings by name:

```
private string GetStringByName(string name)
{
    var id = Resources.GetIdentifier(name, "string", PackageName);
    return id == 0 ? string.Empty : Resources.GetText(id);
}
```

For the colors I don´t know a better way than creating a list (or hashset if you prefer):

```
var colors = new List<int>
{
    Resource.String.dialog_green,
    Resource.String.dialog_red,
    Resource.String.dialog_green,
    Resource.String.dialog_green,
    Resource.String.dialog_green,
    Resource.String.dialog_red,
    etc...
};
```

Then you could get your dialog as follows:

```
var index = mLokacije.IndexOf(pos); // assuming mLokacije is a List<>
var lok_naslov = GetStringByName($"lok{index}_naslov");
var lok_sitno = GetStringByName($"lok{index}_sitno");
var lok_opis = GetStringByName($"lok{index}_opis");

dialog_Informacije informacijeDialog = new dialog_Informacije(lok_naslov,
            lok_sitno,
            lok_opis,
            GetString(colors.IndexOf(index)));
informacijeDialog.Show(transaction, "dialog fragment");
```

For IndexOf to work, I assume the position objects in your array are the same objects you added to markers:

```
var position = new LatLng(50.379444, 2.773611);
mLokacije.Add(position);

MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
options.SetPosition(position);
map.AddMarker(marker1);
```

If IndexOf does not work for any reason, you could find the index as follows:

```
var index = mLokacije.FindIndex(position => position.Lat == pos.Lat && position.Lng == pos.Lng);
```

Comment: Your solution is great, but I have 1 problem. var index = mLokacije.IndexOf(pos); always sets index to 0. Even var indexplus = mLokacije.IndexOf(pos) + 1; and  var indexplus = mLokacije.LastIndexOf(pos) + 1; ...both return 0

Comment: That make me think that the objects in mLokacije list are not the same instances you get from e.Marker.Position. List.IndexOf will work only if you are comparing the same instances, not just the values

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you're saying that markers' LatLngs aren't completely the same objects as my LatLngs? BTW I have found a workaround using two double[] arrays. It's not ideal -  I can only find an IndexOf either the latitude or the longitude, also 2 locations musn't have identical lat or long values. Is it possible to implement this differently so I can compare the both values of LatLng (2D array?) ?

Comment: var indexplusLat = Array.IndexOf(mLats, pos.Latitude) + 1;                                 
var indexplusLong = Array.IndexOf(mLongs, pos.Longitude) + 1;                           
if (indexplusLat != indexplusLong)
{
   Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
    return;
} ...

Comment: Yeah, that´s what I´m saying. The only reason why IndexOf would not work is because the object is not found in the array. Could you possibly be using duplicates for your markers? You could edit your question and add more info about how you actually fill the mLokacije array. Then I could help better

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by using duplicates? I tried accessing the marker through var marker = (Marker)sender; and also through e.Marker

Comment: I drew the markers using the same List<LatLng> that I use to compare the position on a click event. (for loop) (...) options.SetPosition(mLokacije[i]); (...)

Comment: Ok, so comparing it´s not working for any reason. As you say 2 positions cannot be equal you could write a for() statement and compare lat/long to get the index